# Comparar un Input con un registro en una bbdd

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, pdo

Imaginamos que tengo este formulario (Es mucho más grande pero quiero probar solo con un campo):

```
<form id="form1 " action="?action" method="POST">                
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo</th>
      <td>
      <input  id="acronimo" class="requisites" class="form-control"  type="text" name="acronimo"  value="acronimo"/>
      </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

Cuando enviamos el formulario se envia a phpmyadmin por PDO.
Ahora bien, como puedo hacer que lo compare con phpmyadmin porque "Acronimo" seria la PK en la que se inserta y si no existe se ejecute pero si existe que mande un alert diciendo:
"'valor ingresado por usuario' ya exista en la bbdd"

¿Algo así seria?:

```
class CategoriaModel {

private $pdo;


public function __CONSTRUCT() {
    try {
        $this->pdo = new 
PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=deimos1;charset=UTF8', 'root', '');
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $this->pdo->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';SET lc_messages = 'es_ES'");
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}



public function Registrar(Categoria $data) {
try {
    $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO categoria (acronimo,categoria,registro_calidad)
        VALUES (?, ?,?)";

        $this->pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(array(
        $data->__GET('acronimo'),
        $data->__GET('categoria'),
        $data->__GET('registro_calidad')
            )
    );
if($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
echo "se insertó ";
}  else {
echo '<script>alert($acronimo "ya exista en la bbdd");</script>;';
};
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
}
}
```

Comment: en ningún momento estás ejecutando tu select, eso no puede funcionar bien.

Comment: YA lo he modificado poniendo "$this->pdo->prepare" antes del Select, asi no se ejecutaria ya?

Comment: te servirá INSERT IGNORE, o INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEU UPDATE, investiga sobre eso por mientras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el siguiente ejemplo estoy suponiendo una base de datos llamada "test" y una tabla llamada "tabla".

Los registros igual los he puesto directamente, pero debes asumir que son los que estás trayendo con POST.

INSERT IGNORE insertará el dato, solo si la primary key no existe. De otra manera, simplemente ignorará el ingreso de ese dato. Más abajo verifico si hubo inserción de datos y bajo esas condiciones puedes poner lo que quieras hacer cuando se haya insertado o no un registro (si se insertó es que existía, si no se insertó, sí existía):

```
<?php

try {
    $params = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8';
    $db = new PDO($params, 'root', '');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$acronimo=27;
$valor1 = "hola";
$valor2 = "chao";

$insert=$db->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO tabla (laPK, columna1, columna2) VALUES (:pk, :v1, :v2)");
$insert->bindValue('pk',$acronimo);
$insert->bindValue('v1',$valor1);
$insert->bindValue('v2',$valor2);
$insert->execute();
if($insert->rowCount() > 0) {
    echo "se insertó ";
}
else {
    echo "se ignoró";
}

?>
```

Espero que te sirva, también hay una forma de actualizar los datos si ya existe la primary key. Dime si te sirvió este método o necesitas algun otro ejemplo con lo que te menciono.

Comment: antes de ponerme a probar cosas sin sentido mira de nuevo la pregunta formulada debajo de ¿Algo así seria?: e modificado otra vez el codigo con la construcción de la conexion

Comment: Debería funcionar, solo cambia ese INSERT INTO por INSERT IGNORE INTO

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) me da ese erro en la linea del if

Comment: falta un ; (punto y coma) después del paréntesis que está antes del if

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on string Tambien en la linea del If, siento la tonteria del error de antes que me comi un par de ";" xD!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58754/discussion-between-roberto-sepulveda-bravo-and-alberto-cepero-de-andres).

Comment: Problema resuelto había que modificar variables a mi código para que funcionara